# How to display an external content in my website using javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geotargetting

This is my first post!
I have a question about javascript...here is my code:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Geolocation Demo</h1>
    <p>Latitude: <span id="lat">0.00</span> Longitude: <span id="lon">0.00</span> City: <span id="city">Loading...</span></p>
    <p><a id="city_link" href="http://tinygeocoder.com/" target="_blank">View City</a></p>
    <p><a id="gmaps_link" href="http://maps.google.co.uk/" target="_blank">View on Google Maps</a></p>

    <script language="javascript">
       // show the position on the page and make a google maps link
       function showPosition(position) {
         var lat = position.coords.latitude;
         var lon = position.coords.longitude;
         document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = lat;
         document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = lon;

         var gmaps_url = "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=" + lat + "+" + lon;
         var city_url = "http://tinygeocoder.com/create-api.php?g=" + lat + "," + lon;
         document.getElementById("gmaps_link").href = gmaps_url;
         document.getElementById("city_link").href = city_url;
         }
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As you can see, this script target my geolocation. Specifically, Lat and Lon are working perfectly. In addinition, i want to display and region info (like city). So, i found a website which i provide the coordinates and it returns me a region name. My question is if i can display the name of region without clicking the link "View city" but in the field "city"...is it possible to pass the webpage content (http://tinygeocoder.com/create-api.php?g=" + lat + "," + lon;) into my webpage? The content of this page is only the name as i said...no html tags!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX

After you have the url formed make a ajax request to it,
 get the results back and parse into  your container

You might also want to look at the google geocoder example (as when I checked that service it said it was unavailable)

Comment: Yes sorry - if you wanted to use Ajax you would need to create a proxy